# Attemping to replace a vector drawable with image from camera and the drawable gets stretched out behind the image?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some code setup where a user takes a picture using their camera, and it loads onto the page in an existing imageview - when the page loads by default, there's a placeholder image but once they take a picture with their camera, it fills the imageview (sort of) but the image vector still shows up behind it and seems to stretch the entire container out?

For reference, here's two images, a before and an after:

**Before**
[image: Blank profile screen]

**After**
[image: stretched out image above profile data]

All I want is for the image to replace the drawable I have as a placeholder, and fill the width of the container holding it but I'm guessing something in my code must be going wrong somewhere.

Below is the layout file for this page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/edit_profile_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.android.projectrc.activities.ViewProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/edit_profile_app_bar"
            layout="@layout/edit_profile_support_bar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/lighter_gray"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:minHeight="275dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/account_image_background"
                        android:padding="1dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_48px" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name_change_link"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:text="Change Name" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:text="Private Details" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/private_items_recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Optional Details" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/optional_items_recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is the code that loads the camera photo:

```
private fun loadBitmapImage() {
    //get view dimensions
    val maxWidth = profile_image_container.width
    val maxHeight = profile_image_container.height

    //get image dimensions
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mProfilePhotoPath, options)
    Log.i(TAG, "image height :: ${options.outHeight}\nimage width :: ${options.outWidth}\n" +
            "image bitmap :: ${options.inBitmap}")
    //calculate image scaling (if necessary)
    options.inSampleSize = Utilities.calculateInSampleSize(options, maxWidth, maxHeight)

    //now we can load the image
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false
    val smallBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mProfilePhotoPath, options)
    val imageView = profile_image as AppCompatImageView
    imageView.setImageBitmap(smallBitmap)
}
```

And (if necessary) this is the calculateInSampleSize method:

```
fun calculateInSampleSize(
        options: BitmapFactory.Options, reqWidth: Int, reqHeight: Int): Int {
    // Raw height and width of image
    val height = options.outHeight
    val width = options.outWidth
    var inSampleSize = 1

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        val halfHeight = height / 2
        val halfWidth = width / 2

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while (halfHeight / inSampleSize >= reqHeight && halfWidth / inSampleSize >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this has to do with the overall logic of your views, and how you replace the image.

When your app is in the "default" state, the container will be `(w:match_parent, h:275dp)`.

This is what you're basing yourself upon in order to calculate the downsampling of your image.

Now since you are very much unlikely going to take pictures having that ratio (the ratio of your `profile_image_container` linear layout), the `imageView.setImageBitmap(smallBitmap)` you're going to load is not going to fit perfectly.

So here are a couple of suggestions you could think of :

1. Add a scaleType to your ImageView. Here's a link to the representation of each one of them : https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide
2. Make sure to add `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"`

   to your NestedScrollView (so the top doesn't get hidden under the AppBar and your ImageView actually looks centered vertically)
3. Try to rethink how you want to display the image taken from the camera (ratio, or inside your `calculateInSampleSize` function, as you wish).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing and was actually wondering if there was a way to simplify the layout somewhat - I'll keep these in mind though and get back to you should something change!

Comment: Just as an update, your suggestions worked! I ended up setting a static height for the container layout, and setting that as the max height for the imageview (redundant but if I didn't do it that way, it ended up stretching the imageview weirdly) and gave it a centerCrop scaleStyle, thanks a bunch!